# cout not shown when I call std::abort()

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2015, iostream, abort

When I run this code in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 don't see the output

```
That was unexpected
```

It works in gcc 5.3 on Linux.

```
class X {};
class Y {};
class Z : public X {};
class W {};

void f() throw(X, Y)    // list what exceptions can be thrown
{
    int n = 0;
    if (n) throw X(); // OK
    if (n) throw Z(); // also OK
    throw W(); // will call std::unexpected()
}

int main() {
    std::set_unexpected([] {
        std::cout << "That was unexpected" << std::endl;
        std::abort();
    });
    f();
}
```

Comment: You may try writing to `std::cerr` instead.

Comment: I tried std::cerr just now but does still not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual C++ never implemented exception specifications, although the *syntax* is accepted.

Anyway they're deprecated in C++11 and later.

Maybe as a result of the non-conformance of the main Windows C++ compiler.

---

In the same vein, as I recall Visual C++ never implemented `std::uncaught_exception`, but of this I'm not quite sure. Worth checking before using and relying on. … *Doc-checked*: [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1atwat8.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for Visual C++ 2015 states that

> **”** On devices, `uncaught_exception` is only supported on Windows CE 5.00 and higher versions, including Windows Mobile 2005 platforms

So on desktop platforms it's evidently supported.

Comment: Also note that on Windows Clang does the same

Comment: OK, maybe the MS doc is wrong because it does not seem to work on Windows 10 desktop platform.
Thank you for finding this!

Comment: @Damian: You mean `std::uncaught_exception`?

Comment: Yes, std::uncaught_exception does not seem to be called.